# Spring + Wss4j The private key for the supplied alias does not exist in the keystore

Tags: java, spring, soap

Buenas noches comunidad.
Pues llevo varios días rompiéndome la cabeza con este asunto, sucede que estoy utilizando Apache wss4j para asegurar por medio de certificados los llamados a un conjunto de servicios web en SOAP.

Esta configuración la estoy realizando a través de anotaciones por lo que he visto poca documentación referente a este tipo de uso, la mayoría de cosas están documentadas para configuración vía XML.

La configuración del security interceptor es la siguiente:

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor sessionInterceptorNb() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    // set security actions
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken Signature Encrypt");

    // sign the request
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("anyuser");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("anypassword");

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureUser("privatecertuser");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBeanNb().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts("{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");

    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

El problema inició cuando noté que el requerimiento decía que el usuario y contraseña que debe generarse en el tag `UsernameToken` debe ser uno que no necesariamente debe estar configurado en el keystore que estoy utilizando, es decir; no necesito una private key para el usuario que coloque en el método `securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("any user")`
 , no hay problema con eso. El detalle es que al implementar el método `setSecurementSignatureUser` para definir el usuario que si tiene una llave privada dentro del keystore me está arrojando el siguiente error:

```
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The private key for the supplied alias does not exist in the keystore
Original Exception was java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Error during Signature: 
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:163)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:238)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jHandler.doSenderAction(Wss4jHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:574)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando `keytool -list -v -keystore ...` para ver las entradas que contiene el keystore; puedo ver la private key para el usuario privatecertuser, aún así estoy obteniendo el error mostrado.

Realmente no comprendo qué me puede estar faltando o qué hay de mal en la configuración.